# Spring Security OAuth + Spring Boot 2

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

Is the Spring Security OAuth library ( org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2 ) meant to work with Spring Boot 1 & 2 (and therefore Spring Framework 4 & 5)?

When I first started reading about Spring Boot 2's release, I remember reading something about how initially, Spring Security 5 wasn't going to support all the parts it used to (such as the role of resource servers), and how that oauth library was planned to be rolled into the Spring Security library directly. Is that still the plan, or is the OAuth library meant to be used separately?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is meant to work for both as of now. It is the same project that you would have used for oauth in spring security 4.x. For spring security 5 the direction is like you said, move features directly into spring security 5. However this will not happen all at once. So basically if you are using oauth features from that project that have not been rolled into security core, you should import this project separately.

Comment: It is supposed to work but it doesn't seem that seamless. My authorization server is on Spring Boot 1.5 and the applications I've updated to Spring Boot 2 no longer can authenticate. If you have any insight on that it would be greatly appreciated. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53401704/spring-boot-2-oauth2-with-spring-boot-1-5-authorization-server